# Why are Goldbach laggards biased towards $2 \bmod 6$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, experimental-mathematics

For even $n$, let $g(n)$ be the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of two primes $n=p+q$ with $p \le q$. Define $a_k$ to be the largest $n$ with $g(n)=k$. I would bet money that no-one will disprove (in the next 10 years) that $a_k$ for $10 \le k \le 19$ are $632, 692, 626, 992, 878, 908, 1112, 998, 1412, 1202$. One would expect these numbers to have no small odd divisors (and each is a power of 2 times a prime) but I would expect them to be about evenly split between $2 \bmod 6$ and $4 \bmod 6$. Yet all of these are $2 \bmod 6$. Is there a model which  accounts for this? (Update: $a_j$ for $1\le j \le 42$ are all $2 \bmod 6$. The proportion which are $2 \bmod 6$ never goes below 76% for $k \le 5001$. So it is not as blatant as I first thought but still quite pronounced.)

> Is there a (heuristic) reason for this bias in favor of $2 \bmod 6$?

Discussion **(revised thanks to [Gerry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54259/why-are-goldbach-laggards-biased-towards-2-mod-6#comment135481_54259) and [David](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54259/why-are-goldbach-laggards-biased-towards-2-mod-6#comment135432_54259))**: Of course we do not know if $a_k$ is well defined although we suspect it is. Data exists for $g(n)$  up to $2.5 \cdot 10^8$. The estimates are based on the size of n and the set of odd primes dividing it. This would predict that from some point on we never have $g(n+m)<g(n)$ with $n+m$ a multiple of 3 but $n$ not a multiple of 3. That seems to be true (I think). The OEIS has a list of [Conjecturally largest even integer which is an unordered sum of two primes in exactly n ways](http://oeis.org/A000954) and a link from there gives the first 5001 values. Of these all are $2 \bmod 6$ up until entries $43, 48, 70, 81, 88$. Over the entire $5001$ values, $3847$ are $2 \bmod 6$ and $1154$ are $4 \bmod 6$. The proportion which are $2 \bmod 6$ looks like it might converge to $\frac{3}{4}$.

The proportions which are in various congruence classes are
\begin{gather*}
[[0, 1], [2, 3846], [4, 1154]] \bmod 6 \\
[[2, 1536], [4, 911], [6, 874], [8, 1680]] \bmod 10 \\
[[2, 711], [4, 656], [6, 944], [8, 644], [10, 1033], [12, 1013]] \bmod 14 \\
[[0, 663], [2, 636], [4, 637], [6, 583], [8, 647], [10, 606], [12, 613], [14, 616]] \bmod 16.
\end{gather*}

David [suggests](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54259/why-are-goldbach-laggards-biased-towards-2-mod-6#comment135432_54259) that it might relate to prime races and gives a good reference which in turn suggests a relation to congruence classes of squares. I suppose that even a slight advantage can bias the location of the extreme cases, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Multiplication by 2 yields the sequence at http://oeis.org/A000954 but that site doesn't discuss the problem raised here. 

Comment: Numerical data suggests that, for almost all $x$, the number of primes less than $x$ which are $2 \mod 3$ is greater than those which are $1 \mod 3$. The term to search on is "prime race"; here is a friendly introduction http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/granville1.pdf Is this effect strong enough to explain your observations?

Comment: Let's denote by $\pi(x;a,b)$ the number of primes that are $a \pmod{b}$ and $\le x$ (and by $P(x;a,b)$ the set of such primes). The Chebyshev bias that David Speyer mentions says that $\pi(x;1,3)<\pi(x;2,3)$ happens with a very high logarithmic density. This is the only heuristic I've seen to explain the fractal patterns in Goldman's partition function. Though it is very likely that $\pi(x;1,3)<\pi(x;2,3)$, it is almost never likely that $2\pi(x;1,3)<\pi(x;2,3)$. 

Comment: If primes were as randomly distributed as I think they are, then since for $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ you are picking pairs from $\binom{P(2n;1,3)}{2}$, for $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ you are picking pairs from $\binom{P(2n;2,3)}{2}$, and for $n\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ you pick pairs from $P(2n;1,3)\times P(2n;2,3)$, you will likely have $g(3n)>g(3n+2)>g(3n+1)$. Now combining this with the standard growth conjectures on $g(n)$ (meaning, it is roughly increasing :)) this gives some "explanation".

Comment: To expand on David Speyer's comment: suppose that up to $N$ there are 100 primes congruent 2 mod 3, and only 80 congruent 1 mod 3. Then if $N$ is 4 mod 6 it could have as many as 50 Goldbach representations; if 0 mod 6, it could have as many as 80; if 2 mod 6, it can't have more than 40. This could well be why more laggards are 2 mod 6, and no laggards (except 24) are 0 mod 6. You have to go up to 608,981,813,029 before you get more primes 1 than 2 mod 3, which seems to be beyond the range of the Goldbach tables, so testing the hypothesis won't be easy. 

Comment: Let the minutes record that Gjergji's comment wasn't yet visible to me when I posted mine. 

Comment: @Gerry (and Gjergi and David) Yes! that does explain a lot. Of course actually (if I haven't made an error) we would have $1194 \le N \le 1216$ so that the number of primes congruent 1 mod 6 would be between 94 and 96. So it is as many 50 vs no more than 47 or 48. Still that may be enough. And the effect is more pronounced mod 3 than mod p for larger primes because there is no mixing of classes.

Comment: I looked at g(a) and g(b) for a and b twice a prime (to remove the effect of other prime divisors) then it does seem much more balanced (but not totally) if we let a and b each be the jth member of their congruence class mod 6.

Comment: This is also a lovely read: 
http://www.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/MazurLtrMay08.PDF

Comment: The last edit to this question (on April 6, 2014) was a bit extensive, nevertheless I approved the suggested edit by user48851. I checked the correctness of the edit using [this text file](http://oeis.org/A045917/b045917.txt) which lists the number of ways that $2n$ can be written as a sum of two primes for $n\leq 20000$. That file is linked from the corresponding [OEIS sequence A045917](http://oeis.org/A045917).

Comment: @GHfromMO The link you give seems to be broken. I think http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/MazurLtrMay08.PDF works instead.

Comment: @Joel: Thank you, but note that my comment with the link is more than 2 years old. Links come and go!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this whole discussion was old.

Answer (score 1):

I had requested help finding references on this topic but I think that is the answer to this question.

One can use this heuristic procedure to explain why Goldbach's laggards are biased towards $ 2 \bmod 6$:

using these two examples in which they are represented the graphs of possible $p$ and $q $ pairs

case   $ n=96 \equiv 0 \bmod 6$

[image]

$g(96)=7$

case $ n=98 \equiv 2 \bmod 6$

[image]

note the symmetry with respect to $n/2$

$g(98)=3$ also considering that $98=3+95$

it is evident that for $n =p+q $

- if $ n \equiv 0 \bmod 6$ then $p \equiv -1 \bmod 6 $ and $ q \equiv 1 \bmod 6$
- if $ n \equiv 2 \bmod 6$ then $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ and $ q \equiv 1 \bmod 6$

, or $p=3$ and $q \equiv -1 \bmod 6$

- and if  $ n \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ then $p \equiv -1 \bmod 6 $ and $  q \equiv -1 \bmod 6$ , or $p=3$ and $q \equiv 1 \bmod 6$

as you can see some examples in the case of $n \equiv 0 \bmod 6$ the function $g(n)$  can assume a maximum value equal to double compared to the other two cases $n \equiv 2 \bmod6$ and $n \equiv 4 \bmod6$ why ignoring the case in which $p=3$ in these last two cases the possible pairs $p$ and $q $ are symmetrical respect to $n/2$, therefore these two cases reach the value $k$ for $n$ greater.

As regards the prevalence of $2 \bmod 6$ cases, this is due to the fact that the composite numbers $-1 \bmod 6$ are of the type $(6a-1)(6b+1)$ instead those $1 \bmod 6$ are of the type $(6a+1)(6b+1)$ or $(6a-1)(6b-1)$, the latter in addition to having a different distribution and fixed $n$ are slightly higher in number.